# error in my actionscript for a sound slider I'm working on

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

Hello I' trying to make a sound slider in flash, while working on the code for it; I keep on getting this error Scene 1, 'S Action', Frame 352, line 8 1152: A conflict exists with inherited definition flash.display:MoveClip.isPlaying in namespace public. I'm wondering what I done to cause this error and how can  I fix it?

Please get back to me if you can.

```
stop();
import flash.media.SoundTransform;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

var isPlaying:Boolean = true;
var lastPosition:Number = 0;
var mySound:takeachance = new takeachance ;
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var myTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();

myTransform.volume = .5;
slider02_mc.groove02_mc.scaleX = .5;

myChannel = mySound.play(85,5,myTransform);

myChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,
soundCompleteHandler);
function soundCompleteHandler(e:Event):void 
{
    lastPosition=0;
    myChannel.stop();
    msg_mc.text = "Music stoped playing"
    isPlaying = false;
}

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,startSound);
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,stopSound);

function startSound(myEvent:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(!isPlaying)
    {
        myChannel = mySound.play(lastPosition,5,myTransform);
        isPlaying = true;
        msg_mc.text="";

        myChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,
soundCompleteHandler);

  }
}
function stopSound(myEvent:MouseEvent):void
{
    lastPostion = myChannel.position;
    myChannel.stop();
    isPlaying = false;
}

slider02_mc.mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, myfunction);

function myfunction(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    slider02_mc.mc.startDrag(false,new Rectangle(0,0,200,0))

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,xpos);
    function xpos(event:Event)
    {
        var myvolume=(slider02_mc.mc.x)/200;
        slider02_mc.groove02_mc.scaleX = myvolume;
        volume_mc.text = "Volume is"+int(myvolume*100)+"%";
        myTransform.volume = myvolume;
        myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform;
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,myfunction1);

function myfunction1(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    slider02_mc.mc.stopDrag();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,msg);
    function msg(event:Event)
    {
        volume_mc.text="";
    }
}
```

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#isPlaying

Answer (score 1):

Movieclips already have a property called isPlaying. You should change your variable to something else like soundIsPlaying.